# How to determine if an improper integral converges or diverges?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Let's say we have

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$.

I'd like to find the antiderivative and then analyze the integral going from 0 to N as N goes to infinity. However, I don't know how to find this particular primitive, and the online calculators do something that we haven't gone over in class (they use the Gauss error function), which leads me to suspect that there's another way of doing this.

Does anyone have an idea? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: a) Do you really want to mix $x$ and $t$? b) If you just want to know some estimates, then estimate this is reasonably close to $\int_0^1 t^{-1/2} \, dt$.

Comment: You have an $e^{-x}$ in your integrand. Is that $x$ meant to be a $t$? If not, the integrand is much more trivial to deal with since it'd be a constant w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Apologies, had a brain fart. Yes, I meant to have everything be the same variable; fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding an antiderivative is going to be difficult. Seeing if it converges will not,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx=
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx
$$
Now, for $0\leq x\leq 1$, we have 
$$
 \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
and for $1\leq x$, we have 
$$
 \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\leq e^{-x}
$$

Alternatively, enforce the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$, then your integral is 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx=
2\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm du=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Sorry to be dense, but I don't really understand what you're trying to get at in the first part. Would you mind going into a bit more detail? I'm quite new to this. Sorry again.

Comment: Ah, I think I /may/ understand. Are you comparing the terms to other terms which obviously converge? Seeing as they are less than the convergent integrals that you've compared them to, the integral must be convergent?

Comment: @user494405 that's exactly right

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions, but would you mind sharing how you decided on those particular comparisons? What is the general thought process which led you to choose them? Thanks again.

Comment: there are two important facts about this integral: Near $0$, $e^{-x}$ is pretty much $1$, and $\sqrt{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable, so find a way to establish a bound in terms of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, and then for large $x$, bounding by the very convergent $e^{-x}$ seems clear enough. Breaking an integral into a part near a finite point where you are worried about it blowing up, and near infinity is common